# Batch replace data with variable at specific position in a txt

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have two goals.
**Firstly**, I need to find some 16-character-string specifically positioned after the symbol `@`, which can be found somewhere inside my txt file, and save it to a variable called `v1`. Even thought there can be several "@", what is important is that I get the first "@" and this first "@" can be anywhere at random. **Secondly**, I need to replace this specific chunk of data found in `v1` with another variable called `v2`. Both `v1` and `v2` are 16-character-long.

My file is at `d:\msdos\testing.txt` and it has around 3000 lines or even more (see example below). The user cannot have an easy access to its content. All the process of "deleting and replacing" should be done automatically. The other observation is that the characters around `v2` (after replacement) have to be left untouched. By the way, the search character "@" is not on the first line. In fact it can me anywhere in the file.

adflkjsdf@**12346dsf88dfsd16**00vczxv0012554xzcxcz 54df 6d5s4f s5df4s fdsfsfsfsfsewfwefwfwfewfwƒÁ♣)é=E@tF¸ð♣·@t/ó=╣@uæQjèDó♣ÿÿYð·@t|,óÿÿYëÃ»4^ü^ü╣Ë‹WüöÂuÊWüëøƒâðÓ×ú0è♫îôÿÿ_øCD.üû0.♣Úè♫õÿÿÆ·@ð]*^Ã×ÐèÛøÿÿÀtÅÂðùèŽôÿÿð╣èGü╣ÿÿè]*^Ã‹Gü¨íƒàð,9ê‡ß=E@t♫73¸♫ð·@t3ó=­ð·@tQRjèAòÿÿZYë¿»♣4^ü‹Gü¨t~ƒàð,9ê╣wt=0ôÿÿZYÈÁèÈ1ÿ)Ðƒ×ÿ!Ó73▓Ãa▓ÃaÿÿÿƒÀ0U)Âw.÷ƒÅëT.üz|ú0ðèÿÿcd9f·@ð]_^ÃÆ·@d2cji▄♫♫f♣♫♫5b577i▄868dda11f81f72655a55ffa3fa7ce3a2c00cf♣w♣1T5d045opi4336578╣5d╣9d2▓╣╣▄f♣▄13120d694ss2014╣5ja♣♥1eFÃ♣╣9♪5♪eae╣♣5e♣eTab5b5▓777d2IUd04♪5♪8cd9d215d24♫b570♪22637d2ji▄7fd0458cd9fc702263a9fe6b7d73f1314♫bOIU¨&♫765d╣22637b5e6b7d73d♫80ji▄j513120da♣eTÃa§♥694♫O¶§♥I§♥♥q61g67d215▓♫b57022637♣d2♫15▓ab5d╣9d╣♣eTÃa♪5e6b7d73d2▄╣131cV6◙632s6I’’ƒùƒßÿÁèâÿƒÈ0ˆ’ƒùƒßÿÁèƒÈ0ˆG_Ã@B6♫23q♪2§♥1q♥♥5m5p2BÃ♫a♣1eFÃ♥f♣w♣1a1B5l5B5o987W♫LKJEee879d▓7d2╣▄╣╣╣1♥5▓24♫♥b57022637d╣9♣ji▄f♣b5d╣♣9d215▓ab5♫e6b7d7▓▓▓♫V▓▓♫3dji▄4♫b131022876♪86d215d21OIE98222╣tr2♪4♫b▓▓▓570226ƒÀÜ‹0‹ÃƒÀsçfpro79g235flks8971IU3120dÃ

The first part I was able to do it well, as is:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set v2=0000000022200000
set x=d:\msdos\testing.txt
for /f "delims=@ tokens=1*" %%A in (%x%) do set v0=%%B
set v1=%v0:~0,16%
echo %v1% & REM 12346dsf88dfsd16
```

How can I accomplish the second goal?

Comment: Question updated.It has hundreds of lines with hundreds of random words and ugly ASCII characters

Comment: The search string is always in the first line? Or can it be "just anywhere"? Is it guaranteed to be unique (just occurring one time)? Is there only one `@` in the file?

Comment: @Stephan. I can alter the text so that "@" appears only one time in the whole file (if the solution is too complex to several "@" coexisting at the same time at random positions. However, I cannot guarantee its specific position. It can be allocated anywhere at random.

Comment: If there are several `@`, the code has to decide which of them might be the right one. You *might* find I with a proper REGEX (`@` followed by 16 alpha-numerical chars), but I guess that's not sufficient. If you can alter the file  to contain just the one `@`, it gets quite easy to solve it programmatically, but batch isn't the right tool to do it. I'd recommend [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044).

Comment: Is the 16-char-string pure numerical or is it  alphanumerical?

Comment: @Stehan. Alphanumerical

Comment: Please check, if my new answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch isn't the right tool for this. It can be done using REGEX, but batch has no implementation of this. Using dbenhams great [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) makes it easy though:

```
@echo off
SetLocal 
set "v1=@[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}""  & REM this is a REGEX search pattern 
set "v2=@0000000022200000"  & REM this is the replacement string
call jrepl "%v1%" "%v2%" /F testing.txt /M /O -
```

See `jrepl.bat /?` for usage info. In short:

```
jrepl <searchstring> <replacementstring> <switches>
```

where `/F <inputfile>` gives the file to change,
`/M` keeps original line endings (might not be needed here, but to be sure...)
`/O -` overwrites inputfile with the result. Instead of `-` you can also give a file name (`/O testing.new`)

NOTE: This replaces *each* string in the file matching the search pattern.

Comment: Hi Stephan. The txt file has hundreds of lines and the user cannot have easy access to it. All the process has to be done automatically. Your approach is interesting, but it will not be possible to determine what is "pre" and what is"post". The file may have even several "@", but I am aware that the method I described on this example just gets the first "@" and this is not a problem. So, what is our next step if the file is huge?